# Is requiring images in React Native a lightweight operation?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to create an image store for my React Native app. Something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    pic1:     require('image!pic1'),
    pic2:     require('image!pic2'),
    ...
    pic17285: require('image!pic17285')
};
```

I could use it in my components like this:

```
var React      = require('react-native');
var ImageStore = require('./ImageStore');
...
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <React.Image                 
                source={ImageStore.pic1245}
                style={styles.image}
            />
        );
    }
});
```

Is this safe with respect to performance? I can see in Chrome that these require calls return small js objects, but I'm afraid that the images do get loaded on the native side. What happens behind the scenes when I require an image?